# Angular (8) Universal with firebase cloud functions - can't match any routes

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, angular-universal, angular8

UPDATE: I created a new project with every angular update there was and now on 8.2.0 it seems to be working. Just follow the instructions below, BUT there's currently a bug within webpack. So, after building "npm run build:ssr" open the server.js in functions/dist and edit lines 3 & 7 like so:

```
if(typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object')
    module.exports = factory(require("./server/main"));
else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
    define(["require(\"./server/main\")"], factory);
else if(typeof exports === 'object')
    exports["app"] = factory(require("./server/main"));
else
    root["app"] = factory(root["require(\"./server/main\")"]);
```

(before: "factory(require("require(\"./server/main\")"));")

BIG thanks goes out to Michele Da Rin Fioretto for helping me out with this one on "https://blog.daudr.me/painless-angular-ssr/#comment-4605393279". If you were facing the same problem please head over there and thank him for this.

---

I have a working Angular (8) shop webapp, that uses firebase. But since i'm not using Angular-Universal, i can't set title/meta tags on product-sites. To tackle that problem i tried to add angular-universal and deploy the app to firebase cloud-functions, but as soon as firebase takes over, no routes can't be matched anymore.

I followed the official guide on angular.io, then switched over to the tutorial of the brilliant Jeff Delanay of fireship.io [link to the tutorial](https://fireship.io/lessons/angular-universal-firebase/) and read some medium articles on this topic [like this one](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering). I created (several) new apps and tried it repeatedly. Everything works fine (except the new angular 8 lazy loading arrow function) as long as the ssr-express server handles requests. "npm run build:ssr" followed by "npm run serve:ssr" works great, but as soon as the code gets prepped for firebase cloud functions and "firebase serve" takes over, "localhost:5000" works, but opening any link directly, like the "/about" example, console output states that no routes could be matched. Since i tried the official documentation and several medium articles, this has to be a very common problem, but i couldn't find any questions on here regarding this topic.

Since i can't see how this would be reviewable on stackblitz or anywhere else, i'll try to describe (briefly) what i did and show the corresponding code where required.

tl;dr: (outdated)
[Firebase Server](https://cloudfunctionsangularuniversal.web.app/)
[Github Repo](https://github.com/GerritHillebrecht/cloudfunctionsangularuniversal)

(basically open the firebase server, click the button and hit f5)

The necessary prebuilt:

```
ng new cloudfunctionsangularuniversal && cd cloudfunctionsangularuniversal
ng add @angular/fire
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject cloudfunctionsangularuniversal
ng g c landing
ng g c ssrtesting
```

/src/app/app-routing.module.ts: Update Routes

```
//..
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LandingComponent },
  { path: 'ssrtesting', component: SsrtestingComponent }
];
```

Since i want to use firebase in my project, i need the XMLHttpRequest variable

```
npm install ws xhr2 bufferutil utf-8-validate  -D
```

/server.ts: Update the Server with the just installed packages

```
(global as any).WebSocket = require('ws');
(global as any).XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');
// ...
```

At this point "npm run build:ssr" followed by "npm run serve:ssr" fires up an express server, which handles all incoming requests properly.

But to use the app with firebase, several changes are necessary.

Init firebase (choose functions&hosting)

```
firebase init
```

/firebase.json: rewrite all traffic to a function.

```
//...
"hosting": {
  "public": "dist/browser",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ],
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "**",
      "function": "ssr"
    }
  ]
},
//...
```

/server.ts: export the app const, then remove the call to listen.

```
export const app = express();
// ...
// app.listen(PORT, () => {
//   console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
// });
```

/webpack.server.config.js: Make your app a library

```
// ...
output: {
    // Puts the output at the root of the dist folder
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    library: 'app',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
// ...
```

/movedist.js: Create a helper that copies over the build app from your "dist" folder to "functions/dist"

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');

(async() => {

    const src = './dist';
    const copy = './functions/dist';

    await fs.remove(copy);
    await fs.copy(src, copy);

})();
```

install the required package

```
npm i --save fs-extra
```

/package.json: Update your build command

```
//...
"build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server && node movedist && cd functions && npm run build"
//...
```

Finally, create the used app
/functions/src/index.ts

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
const universal = require(`${process.cwd()}/dist/server`).app;

export const ssr = functions.https.onRequest(universal);
```

Now run

```
npm run build:ssr
```

Everything should be ready, so test it with

```
firebase serve
```

When opening "localhost:5000" everything seems fine. But open it up in the incognito window and open "localhost:5000/ssrtesting" and the console will give you

> "ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'cloudfunctionsangularuniversal/us-central1/ssr/ssrtesting'"

before successfully rendering the page. That doesn't happen on the firebase server thogh. Online it fires a 404.

[Firebase Server](https://cloudfunctionsangularuniversal.web.app/)
[Github Repo](https://github.com/GerritHillebrecht/cloudfunctionsangularuniversal)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/kamilmysliwiec/universal-nest ?

Comment: facing same issue from ages.

Comment: make sure you have an empty route in your app-routing.module ```{ path: '', component: AppComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `/^firebase/` inside `externals` in `webpack.server.config.js`

Comment: we only have to do this if you are bundling with --bundleDependencies all, but the work around is to use --bundleDependencies none